# How to allow certain URLs with angular and collect data from them

Tags: angular

I am trying to set up a referral system for my angular website. My website is currently one component accessible at localhost:4200. I want users to be able to use referral codes when accessing the website, so think 'localhost:4200/r/h7Gt4p'.

How do I get my angular page to load what's in the main component when someone navigates to the URL with a referral tag in it. Additionally, how do I then grab the referral parameter from the URL in my typescript file?

I really appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please, provide more info on efforts you made and share some code.

Comment: Did you go through the [angular routing](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#routing) docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to create a new `ReferralComponent` as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-referral',
  templateUrl: './referral.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./referral.component.css']
})
export class ReferralComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const code = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('code');
    // Process your code here. Then redirect
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }
}
```

Then configure routes for your app:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'r/:code',
    component: ReferralComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HelloComponent
  }
]
```

Find a running example here: https://angular-app-initial-route.stackblitz.io/r/h7Gt4p

Open your browser's console to see the captured code. I hope it helps!

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much this is super helpful!

Comment: Happy to help! @RyanSoderberg

Comment: For some reason, I am getting null as the value of the code. Would you mind taking a look? I uploaded them here due to char limit
https://repl.it/repls/HarshIllegalOs

Answer (score 1):

First, you should set up a new routing path, more on that ([here](https://angular.io/guide/router)). I'd recommend something like

```
{ path: 'r/:refId', component: ReferralComponent }
```

This also requires you to create a referralComponent, from where you can handle the id. Using the router inside your component, you can grab the params from the url by using router.url[0] if I remember correctly. I might have misunderstood your question though, if so, please be more specific and I'll try to help out some more.